# ERROR: attempt to index global object a nil value: corona SDK

Tags: android, ios, coronasdk, null

I'm getting the error:

**Runtime error
...n-stylr\documents\corona projects\happy_day\game.lau:50: attempt to index global 'city1' (a nil value)**

My code is as follows:

```
function scene:createScene(event)

local screenGroup = self.view

local background = display.newImage("background1.jpg")

local city1 = display.newImage("bild.png")
city1:setReferencePoint(display.BottomLeftReferencePoint)
city1.x = 0
city1.y = 640
city1.speed = 1

local city2 = display.newImage("bild.png")
city2:setReferencePoint(display.BottomLeftReferencePoint)
city2.x = 1136
city2.y = 640
city2.speed = 1

local city3 = display.newImage("build2.png")
city3:setReferencePoint(display.BottomLeftReferencePoint)
city3.x = 0
city3.y = 640
city3.speed = 2

local city4 = display.newImage("build2.png")
city4:setReferencePoint(display.BottomLeftReferencePoint)
city4.x = 1136
city4.y = 640
city4.speed = 2
end

function scene:enterScene(event)

Runtime:addEventListener("touch", touchScreen)
print(city1)
city1.enterFrame = scrollCity
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", city1)

city2.enterFrame = scrollCity
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", city2)

city3.enterFrame = scrollCity
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", city3)

city4.enterFrame = scrollCity
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", city4)

end
```

Comment: please give your question a convenient title. Most people asking here have an issue and can't find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare`local city1` outside the `createScene` function and create `city1` as:

```
local city1;

function scene:createScene(event)
   -- your code for localGroup and bg 

   city1 = display.newImage("bild.png")  -- just create city1 as this

   -- do the rest of your code
end
```

If the error occurs reffering other cities(city2 ,3 or 4), do the same methode for all those.

Keep coding................ :)